# amParse date shows one day off

Tags: angular-moment

I am using [Angular Moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) for date formatting. I am using time ago and parse filters to show the dates in 'how many days ago' format.

```
am-time-ago="myObject.myDateInMMDDYYYYFormat | amParse:'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'
```

But the output that shows is off by one day for all the dates except current date. i.e. For today(11/27) it shows correctly as '..hours ago' but for (11/26) it directly shows '2 days ago' instead of 'yesterday' and so on. Am I missing any configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was that I was not passing time stamp(11/27/2015). After passing time stamp(11/27/2015 14:10:45) its working properly.